# Start Workflow Externally

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to start a SharePoint 2013 workflow from a system external to SharePoint? For example, from a CRM system using a web service call.

If so, how is it done?

Note: in some scenarios no item may exist in SharePoint for the workflow to run on when starting it externally.

Comment: It's possible but What's the scenario that you need to run workflow on empty list items ?! we may suggest another good solution based on your requirement

Comment: I want the solution options for both if an item exists or doesn't. In the scenario where an item doesn't exist the workflow might just send an email alert for example but needs to be triggered from an external system.

Comment: Keep an eye on Microsoft Flow, its growing fast in capabilities